# Electric toothbrush: Role of spring in contact-less charging

Tags: coil, induction

I accidentally dropped our electric toothbrush on the floor and the bottom lid came undone. I want to fix the toothbrush and make it watertight again. I would glue the lid back on, but this is impeded by this spring that counteracts closing the lid. Normally this is no problem, but the lid does not snap shut anymore. Also, I'm not sure which purpose it even fulfills - the innards definitely stay in place without it (even when shaking the case). I put the toothbrush back together without the spring, put it on the charger and it charged alright.

What purpose does this spring fulfill? What could happen if I glued the toothbrush shut without it?

[image: Looking straight up the bottom]
Looking straight up the bottom - this is where the spring inserts

[image: Overview]
Overview - main piece to the left, lid with spring on the right.

Comment: Looks like purely mechanical purpose - that is to push the components so they don't wiggle inside, perhaps to ensure some contact inside.

Comment: Is the spring ferro-magnetic?

Comment: @tdtsc Sorry about earlier - the spring *is* ferro-magnetic.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up gluing it together without the spring. I figured that without it, the worst case is that the device no longer loads or some components come lose, but with it, the worst case is that the glue doesn't really seal it and you get a shock.

So far, it's still charging and nothing seems to be lose.